# unable to find that exists and not an iframe using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm making a project which goes to my orders page on amazon and collects data like product name, price, delivery date using selenium (cuz there is no api for that, and cant do with bs4). I get login and get to orders page without any problem.But I'm stuck where i have to find the delivery date using find element by class( I chose class because all other delivery date text have same class), but selenium says it cannot find it.

No, its not in an iframe as i cant see the option for `This Frame` when i right click on that element.

here is the code -

```
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
import time
userid = #userid
passwd = #passwd

browser = webdriver.Chrome()

browser.get('https://www.amazon.in/gp/your-account/order-history?ref_=ya_d_c_yo')

email_input = browser.find_element_by_id('ap_email')
email_input.send_keys(userid)
email_input.submit()
passwd_input = browser.find_element_by_id('ap_password')
passwd_input.send_keys(passwd)
passwd_input.submit()
time.sleep(5)
date = browser.find_element_by_class_name('a-color-secondary value')
print(date.text)
```

Finding element by xpath seems to work, but fails to find the date for all orders as xpath is different for every element.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refers to this line:

```
date = browser.find_element_by_class_name('a-color-secondary value')
```

It seem like your element target having multiple class name, `a-color-secondary` and `value`. Sadly `.find_element_by_class_name` just for single class name.

Instead you can use `.find_element_by_css_selector`:

```
date = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.a-color-secondary.value')
```